# Describing an event from past

Tags: usage

Suppose I have been going to a restaurant regularly and for the last few days I was unable to go there. My friend accompanies me as well. Is it right to say it like this?

> It's been days since we have gone there?

Comment: Yes. More idiomatic: *We haven't gone there for days.*

Answer (score 1):

Lately, we haven't been able to go there.

Comment: Sorry William, I gave you second downvote because to me it seemed obvious Muhammad wasn't asking for some different phrase which might work, but for correction of what he first suggested.

I also think the Question belongs not here but in *English Language Learners*.